# Screen Scrape Table, Clean Up, and Load to Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was experimenting with a few ways to loop through TR elements and TE elements and found out how to loop through these rows in a table to import the data I wanted to fetch.  Then, I found an even easier way to fetch the same data, without using a loop.  Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd            
url = "https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/holidays/holidays.asp?display=market&exchange=SGO"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
print(table.prettify())
```

The only problem is that the data comes in with all the HTML formatting, like this.

```
<table id="holidayTable">
 <tr>
  <th class="left light" colspan="3">
   Holiday
  </th>
  <th class="left light">
   Markets Closed
  </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="bold left" valign="top">
   01/01/2018
```

How can I clean this data and load it into a data frame?  I want it to look essentially like this.

[image]

Thanks for your time to look at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the same in a slightly different manner, you can check out the following approach. Used `[1:]` within the script to kick out `th` values. I've tried to shake off the redundancy:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 

url = "https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/holidays/holidays.asp?display=market&exchange=SGO"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
data = pd.DataFrame()

for rows in soup.find(id='holidayTable').find_all('tr')[1:]:
    tds = [row.text for row in rows.find_all('td')]
    add_list_to_df = pd.DataFrame([tds])
    data = data.append(add_list_to_df)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Header1":data[0],"Header2":data[1],"Header3":data[2],"Header4":data[3]}).to_string(index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Works perfect!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Simple way would be to do:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/holidays/holidays.asp?display=market&exchange=SGO"

dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = dfs[0]
```

But it's a good example to practice BeautifulSoup with since it's pretty clean with the tags. You found the table tag, now you just need to iterate through the rows and place them into a dataframe.

first I initialize a blank dataframe to store my results:

`results = pd.DataFrame()`

Then I find all the `tr` tags in the table you stored:

`rows = table.find_all('tr')`

Next for each row, I find the data tagged `td` and put into a list:

```
data = row.find_all('td')
row_data = [ x.text for x in data ]
```

I put that into a temporary dataframe that I use to append to my initial results dataframe:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame([row_data])
results = results.append(temp_df)
```

Then last I drop the null row and reset the index. I don;t know what you want the columns to be, but you can rename the columns in the last line. Or the column headers are usually the `th` tag of the table, you could always go back and get those.

**Full Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd            
url = "https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/holidays/holidays.asp?display=market&exchange=SGO"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]


results = pd.DataFrame()
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    row_data = [ x.text for x in data ]
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([row_data])

    results = results.append(temp_df)

results = results.dropna(how='all').reset_index(drop = True)
results.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
```

Comment: Whoa!  Swwweeetttt!  So, the process of converting the table to a data frame literally cleans up everything.  Good to know!!  Thanks for the help with this one!!